# The iterator of a map doesn't hold the correct value

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator

I have the following function:

```
   void send_sequence_to_device( std::map<const string_t,device_t*> &msg2device_p, std::vector<response_t>& result_list, ushort num_attempts)
    {
        cout<<"sarit enter to send_seq_device"<<endl;
        std::map<const string_t, device_t*>::iterator msg_itf;
        for( msg_itf=msg2device_p.begin(); msg_itf!=msg2device_p.end(); msg_itf++ )
        {
            cout<<"sarit enter to seq"<<msg_itf->first<<endl;
        }
    }
```

I call thhis function by another function:

```
void node_layer_manager_t::ts_clk_est_job_function(void)
{
    vector<response_t> res;
    map<const string_t, device_t*> setRegMsg={{"trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt "+NUM_FRAMES_TO_COUNT_IN_TS_CLK_EST,&trx},{"trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt "+NUM_FRAMES_TO_COUNT_IN_TS_CLK_EST,&trx}}, getRegMsg={{"trx_get_jr_estim_params",&trx},{"trx_get_jr_estim_params",&trx}};
    cout<< "sarit ts clk function nlm first"<<endl;
    send_sequence_to_device(setRegMsg,res);
}
```

NUM_FRAMES_TO_COUNT_IN_TS_CLK=3 (define)

For some reason for example for the first pair {`"trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt "+NUM_FRAMES_TO_COUNT_IN_TS_CLK_EST,&trx}` the `send_sequence_to_device` func print only part of what it should. "estim_fs_to_cnt" instead of "trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt 5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are trying to concatenate your string with an integer:

```
"trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt " + 1
```

does not become `"trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt 1"`, it instead becomes `"rx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt "`

This happens, because in c and c++ a string literal defaults to the type `const char*` and when you add a number to a pointer the pointer will be incremented by this value.

You can use a stringstream instead:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "trx_set_jr_estim_fs_to_cnt " << NUM_FRAMES_TO_COUNT_IN_TS_CLK_EST;
map<const string_t, device_t*> setRegMsg={{ss.str(),&trx},[...]
```